# Simplifying expressions with ReplaceAll: _Real not matching a number

Tags: replacement

I'm learning to simplify expressions and make substitutions. So I made up this example to check my understanding:

```
Exp[I 5] /. Exp[I x_Real] :> Cos[x] + I Sin[x]
```

I expected to get

```
Cos[5] + I Sin[5]
```

However, Mathematica returns

```
Exp[I 5]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Look at the `FullForm`. Also, `MatchQ[5, _Real]` is False.

Comment: Your rule considers Exp with a Times expression, whereas the exponent in Exp[I 5] is Complex[0, 5]. So it does not work. Use  Exp[Complex[a_, b_] ]:>Exp[a](Cos[b]+I Sin[b]) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two important things to understand are:

- Pattern matching is purely structural. It is unaware of the mathematical meaning of expressions.
- `Real` is a datatype. It is a programming concept, not a mathematical one. None of `5`, `5I` or `5.0 I` are `Real`.

```
Head /@ {5, 5.0, 5 I, 5.0 I}
(* {Integer, Real, Complex, Complex} *)

FullForm /@ {5, 5.0, 5 I, 5.0 I}
(* {5,5.`,Complex[0,5],Complex[0.`,5.`]} *)
```

You can use

```
Exp[5 I] // ExpToTrig
(* Cos[5] + I Sin[5] *)
```

or

```
Exp[5 I] /. Exp[z_] :> Exp[Re[z]] (Cos[Im[z]] + I Sin[Im[z]])
(* Cos[5] + I Sin[5] *)
```